# prefixing each N occurrences but from a specific numeral prefix

Tags: awk, count, suffix

My source file:

**0.txt:**

```
[dog$#@.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@.txt ;`ffxx00`]
```

I have the following command that prefixing a number using a count every 2 `.txt` occurs:

```
$ awk -v n=2 '{ newline=""; while ( x=index($0,".txt")) { if(cnt%n==0) pfx++; newline=newline substr($0,1,x-1) pfx substr($0,x,3) ; $0=substr($0,x+3); cnt++} print newline $0}' 0.txt 

[dog$#@1.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@1.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@2.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@3.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@3.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@3.txt ;`ffxx00`]
```

but I would like to start the count from specific numeral prefix, for example *3* such that my result was like this:

```
[dog$#@3.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@3.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@4.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@4.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@5.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@5.txt ;`ffxx00`]
```

Comment: Fix that `$` in the `index` to `$0` and start the awk with `awk -v pfx=2 -v n=2 ...` and you are all set.

Comment: @JamesBrown Sorry, while trying to find a solution I erased without wanting `0` where says `index($0,`. I had understood the use of `pfx++` but I did not pay attention to what I could do with it,

Comment: @JamesBrown ok, I did what I said and it was just what I needed, so now it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
printf ".txt%.0s\n" {1..6} >0.txt # makes your example...
```

You can try:

```
awk -v n=2 -v start=3 '
/^\.txt$/{  print start $O
            if (++cnt%n==0) start++
}
' 0.txt
```

Prints:

```
3.txt
3.txt
4.txt
4.txt
5.txt
5.txt
```

---

With the update (grrr) this outputs the desired output with the input:

```
awk -v n=2 -v start=3 '
/\.txt /{
replacement=start ".txt "
sub(/\.txt /, replacement, $0)
if(++cnt%n==0) start++
} 1
' 0.txt
```

Prints:

```
[dog$#@3.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@3.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@4.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@4.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@5.txt ;`ffxx00`]
[dog$#@5.txt ;`ffxx00`]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my question used simple content for `0.txt`, my real need requires situations where `.txt` is among other strings, I think you should use `/.*\.txt/` to ignore anything before search pattern, but I already tried this and it did not work

Comment: Please have a more realistic example then!

Comment: i am update question.

Comment: My real case involves files with a huge amount of data and thousands of different symbols, but user JamesBrown comment solution worked for these large files. Now trying your last update again, I did not have the expected exit. every thanks!